# WinXP install error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I'm using a WinXP build disk to install XP onto a tower PC.  After doing a full NTFS format, and during the installation process, an error pops up saying:

> SXS.dll: Syntax error in manifest or policy file
>
> d:\i386\asms\10\MSFT\windows\gdiplus\gdiplus.man on line 4
>
> Error: installation failed D:\i386\asms
>
> Error message: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)

The CD has been used many times before without any issue.  Any ideas if this is a disk issue, or hardware issue?

**Update**: I've confirmed the disc works on another machine, so I will try replacing the CD-ROM drive in the PC in question.

Comment: I found this on an HDD.  The user had issues, and whilst I was trying to recover files, I learned I could not access the user's document folder due to this error.  I used Easy Disk Driver Repair and it claimed to have fenced off 5 broken sectors, but couldn't fetch the data.  http://www.snapfiles.com/get/eddr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclic redundancy error specifically refers to errors encountered in reading from a disk or file. In an install, this generally means the source file, or, in this case, the CD.

Does the CD work in another computer right now?

If it does, has it worked in this CD drive before?

The problem could possibly be a CD drive that doesn't handle that sort of CD very well (amazingly enough, that happens more often than we'd like to think), or it means the disk itself is bad.

Good news is, if it's the disk, XP install ISO's can be found very easily as Torrents (only get the ones well rated and downloaded a lot, this lessens your chance of getting one laced with a deeply installed viral payload).

Comment: I replaced the CD-ROM drive and the install proceeded without error.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the memory of the computer by using a utility such a [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).  Memory problems can cause files to be corrupted during copying, causing these types of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that specific error but there are generally only three issues that I run into during an install that are data related.

1. As music2myear said, the install CD or the CD/DVD drive could be bad/dusty.
2. As DragonLord said, the memory could be bad and should be tested with memtest (which is on every major live CD these days).
3. The hard drive could be bad and should be tested for back blocks or reallocated sectors (If it has even just one, replace the drive). You can hook it up to another system and check it with HD Tune or you can load a live CD like Knoppix and install smartmontools to check the S.M.A.R.T status... even though the hard drive error reporting is not very reliable.

Comment: I've found the bad/unreliable CD or DVD drive to be the most common cause of this problem.